# Concatenate string with strcpy

Tags: c

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {

 char f[] = "First";
 char s[] = "Second";
 char *tmp = malloc(strlen(f) + strlen(s) + 2);
 strcpy(tmp, f);
 strcpy(tmp, s);
 printf("%s", tmp);
 free(tmp);
 return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to concatenate f and s. The problem is that tmp contains only "Second" as a array.
What I miss here

Comment: swap the two strcpy lines around, you'll see it just says "first" it could also say "firstd"

Comment: @Joseph Le Brech: I'm really interested in how that would happen?

Comment: isn't strcpy, copying to the beginning of the string and not appending. wouldn't you have to strcpy to &(*tmp+sizeOf(tmp). or what @dasblinkenlight wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using `strcpy`, your code should be slightly modified:

```
int main() {
    const char *f = "First";
    const char *s = "Second";
    char *tmp = malloc(strlen(f) + strlen(s) + 1);
    strcpy(tmp, f);
    strcpy(tmp+strlen(f), s);
    printf("%s", tmp);
    free(tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

You should consider using `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` for safety reasons. Also, `strcat` is a more conventional function for concatenating C string.

**EDIT** Here is an example of using `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`

```
#define MAX 1024

int main() {
    const char *f = "First";
    const char *s = "Second";
    size_t len_f = min(strlen(f), MAX);
    size_t len_s = min(strlen(s), MAX);
    size_t len_total = len_f + len_s;
    char *tmp = malloc(len_total + 1);
    strncpy(tmp, f, len_f);
    strncpy(tmp+len_f, s, len_s);
    tmp[len_total] = '\0';
    printf("%s", tmp);
    free(tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's absolutely no benefits from using `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()` in this very case. That's like Microsoft forcing functions with `_s` suffix everywhere.

Comment: `strncpy` should **never** be used unless you're working with fixed-width, not-necessarily-terminated string fields in structures/binary files.

Comment: @sharptooth There is indeed no reason to use `strncpy` in toy cases, such as this one. However, it is very important to get into a habit of using `strncpy` without thinking twice, to avoid using `strcpy` when it may *really* matter. For example, if you change this very program to take `f` and `s` as parameters, switching to `strncpy` becomes imperative in multithreaded environments. Otherwise, malicious code could move the terminating zero in one of the strings between you calling `malloc(strlen(f) + strlen(s) + 1)` and the calls to `strcpy`. You'd need to limit `strlen(f) + strlen(s)` too.

Comment: @R.. I **strongly** disagree with you on this. Please see my reply to sharptooth to see why.

Comment: Well you're wrong. `strncpy` is not for bounded copying. You're confusing it with the BSD function `strlcpy`. The only easy-to-use, safe, general-purpose string assembly function in C is `snprintf` and unless you really know what you're doing and have a good reason not to, you should always just use `snprintf`.

Comment: @R.. To eliminate guesswork, I added an example of using `strncpy` to implement *bounded copying* in the answer.

Comment: @R.. I genuinely think that I am missing your point here: could you please explain in what way `memcpy` is better than (or for that matter, is different from) `strncpy` in my example above? As far as I know, `strncpy` would not read past `'\0'` of the source string, should one be inserted after taking the length but before copying, and pad the rest of the output buffer with `'\0'`, while `memcpy` would blindly copy `len` bytes from one place to the other.

Comment: `strncpy` will work here, but using `strncpy` like this is like using `wcschr` to search for an integer in an array of integers. It happens to work, but its use is non-idiomatic and just plain wrong. The behavior of `strncpy` is to copy bytes until either a null byte is encountered or the length limit is reached, then zero-pad the destination to the specified length if the null byte was reached before the length limit was reached. This is complicated behavior that can lead to failure-to-terminate issues or wasteful zero-filling (sometimes making O(1) operations become O(n))...

Comment: `memcpy`, on the other hand, is the standard and idiomatic function to use when you want to copy a specific, known number of chars. It makes it clear to the reader that you know what you're doing and know exactly how many bytes will be read and written.

Comment: @R.. I understand your desire to bend definitions slightly to suite your argument, but `memcpy` copies a specific known number of *bytes*, not *chars*. This is quite evident from the signature of `memcpy`, featuring prominently a `void*` in the corresponding position. On the other hand, `strncpy` takes *chars* - again, quite conspicuously. But it is OK, I see your point. Thanks!

Comment: Bytes and chars are the same thing, per the C standard. (Actually there are some subtle differences in where/how the terms are used, but they're fully equivalent.)

Answer (score 6):

`strcpy` copies the string to the beginning of the destination, you want `strcat` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The second `strcpy` overwrites the previous one. Both copy its content to the tmp pointer (at the start of it). You should use `tmp+strlen(f)`.

Or even better use `strcat`.

And even better use more secure methods like: `strncpy`, `strncat`, etc..

Comment: Neither `strncpy()` nor `strncat()` provide any additional safety in this case.

Comment: @Throwback1986: The `n`-versions add no (exactly zero) benefits here.

Comment: @sharptooth: Yes, I hope he didn't paste his whole code here, where it probably would make sense to use n-versions.

Comment: @sharptooth: Agreed, but it can't hurt to get new programmers in the habit of using them.

Comment: -1 for recommending "n" versions. They do not do what you think.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `strcat` instead of your second `strcpy` call, like this:

```
strcpy(tmp, f);
strcat(tmp, s);
```

Note also that allocating `strlen(f) + strlen(s) + 1` bytes for `tmp` is sufficient no need to allocate `strlen(f) + strlen(s) + 2` bytes. After concatenation, you'll get only one string, so only one null character is required.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you copy the second string in place of the first one (the first parameter of `strcpy()` is where to *copy* the string) and this effectively overwrites the first string. Here's an idea of what you need:

```
size_t firstLen = strlen( f );
size_t secondLen = strlen( s );    
char *tmp = malloc(firstLen + secondLen + 1);
strcpy(tmp, f);
strcpy(tmp + firstLen, s);
```

This can be achieved by using `strcat()`, although that would lead to an extra scan along the copied string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct idiomatic safe way to do what you want:

```
size_t l = strlen(f);
char *tmp = malloc(l + strlen(s) + 1);
strcpy(tmp, f);
strcpy(tmp+l, s);
```

or:

```
size_t l = strlen(f) + strlen(s) + 1;
char *tmp = malloc(l);
snprintf(tmp, l, "%s%s", f, s);
```

I tend to prefer the latter unless you're writing embedded systems code where you want to avoid pulling in `printf` dependency.

Finally, note that you should be testing `malloc` for failure, and that it's useless and harmful to allocate memory and copy the strings if all you want to do is print them - you could just do the following:

```
printf("%s%s", f, s);
```

Comment: Ugh! If you must use single-letter identifiers, at least do not use lowercase L (or uppercase i).

Comment: @pmg that's also the first thing that struck me ;)

Answer (score 1):

using strcat() instead, which means append a string accroding to the MSDN doc.strcpy() just means copy a string. If you don't want to use strcat(), you should point out the position by using strncpy() or strcpy_s(). Please refer to the document.